# HTML in DSpace messages

Tags: html, email, dspace

We like to add HTML-layout to eMail messages as send by DSpace.
 Simple adding HTML-tags to one of the eMail templates as 'subscription' does not work.
I suppose we have to do some Java programming, but I have no idea where to start.
Does anyone of you has experience with HTML in DSpace eMails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding HTML tags in the EMail can be done, but this requires some changes to the default EMail class.

It consists of the following changes:

- When setting the text on the actual message sent, an additional subType can be added (Check : https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/core/Email.java#L293). By default this takes a text and the charset, but has an additional "subType". Setting this to "html" enables the message to properly check for tags.
- In the "EMail" class, you could add an additional "subType" variable which defaults to "plain" for example, and can be overwritten through a setter. (I'd refrain from simply setting it to html for every email template as the checking for existing tags might break other templates and also take some extra time).
- The actual code that calls the "subscription" template can then create the mail and set the subtype properly.
- See example images for the difference between the "plain" and "html" subtype.

  ["plain" subtype vs "html" subtype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB2VW.png)

Comment: Thank you Jonas for explaining which script I have to edit.<br />The

Comment: The next question I have is: which part of the scripts will convert the template with html-tags to a proper formatted message? Or should it still be written?

Comment: The parsing of html tags is already present in the currently used code.
The EMail class uses the following to create the actual mail to send.
MimeMessage  contains the actual content, recipients, sentDate etc to use while sending the mail. This class will take care of the parsing from html tags to a correctly formatted mail

Check the documentation of "MimeMessage" for more information. (This has 3 "setText" methods which let you call the method with more specific parameters.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setText-java.lang.String-

Comment: If you want a quick example.
This adds html tags to the "change_password" template and sets the subtype to the used EMail object.
https://github.com/jonas-atmire/DSpace/commit/394bebd3122c203a99a6d426b9bff1ebd74b0f4c

It might be a good idea to try and make it possible to remove the required codechanges (setting the subtype through code) but rather have some flag in the actual template. I'll take a look into that later.
You can try setting up a fake smtp server to see the end result (fake-smtp for example)

Hope this helps

Comment: Jonas, with your script modifications I got it working. Thanks a lot!